# Erroneous postgresql configuration file for ODC

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to use ODC and to do that I need to use postgresql as documentation, the documentation is in this link https://datacube-core.readthedocs.io/en/lates/ops/db_setup.html. I'm in the ubuntu environment 18.04. But I can not. My intentions are to set it with the default settings and then conduct some tests.

```
sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser vincenzo
sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER USER vincenzo WITH PASSWORD '1234';"
createdb -U vincenzo datacube
datacube system init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vincenzo/yes/envs/cubeenv/bin/datacube", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('datacube==1.7rc1+12.gc38de8e2', 'console_scripts', 'datacube')()
  File "/home/vincenzo/yes/envs/cubeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Click-7.0-py3.6.egg/click/core.py", line 764, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vincenzo/yes/envs/cubeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Click-7.0-py3.6.egg/click/core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/vincenzo/yes/envs/cubeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Click-7.0-py3.6.egg/click/core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/vincenzo/yes/envs/cubeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Click-7.0-py3.6.egg/click/core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/vincenzo/yes/envs/cubeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Click-7.0-py3.6.egg/click/core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/vincenzo/yes/envs/cubeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Click-7.0-py3.6.egg/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vincenzo/yes/envs/cubeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datacube-1.7rc1+12.gc38de8e2-py3.6.egg/datacube/ui/click.py", line 186, in new_func
    parsed_config = config.LocalConfig.find(paths=paths, env=specific_environment)
  File "/home/vincenzo/yes/envs/cubeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datacube-1.7rc1+12.gc38de8e2-py3.6.egg/datacube/config.py", line 121, in find
    env=env,
  File "/home/vincenzo/yes/envs/cubeenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/datacube-1.7rc1+12.gc38de8e2-py3.6.egg/datacube/config.py", line 99, in __init__
    raise ValueError('No ODC environment, checked configurations for %s' % fallbacks)
ValueError: No ODC environment, checked configurations for ['default', 'datacube']
```

Comment: this is a .datacube.conf
[datacube]
db_database: datacube

# A blank host will use a local socket. Specify a hostname (such as localhost) to use TCP.
db_hostname:

# Credentials are optional: you might have other Postgres authentication configured.
# The default username otherwise is the current user id.
# db_username:
# db_password:

Comment: What is ODC? Perhaps you could add a tag that clarifies that.

Comment: ODC is Open data cube